# How to declare / implement a Swift function with a nullable pointer argument in Objective-c?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

My Swift code has this:

```
@objc protocol MyDelegate {
    func buttonPressed(buttonNum: Int, packet: Packet?)
}
```

Then my objective-c code for the delegate has this:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(NSInteger)buttonNum :(Packet * _Nullable) packet {
}
```

But I'm getting a "function not implemented" warning.  My experiments seem to indicate that there's something wrong with that nullable pointer.  I.e. if there was no "?" in the Swift proto declaration and no "_Nullable" in the Object-c function then all is well.

Does anyone know what I need to do on the Objective-c side to implement that function for that proto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not due to the nullability of the parameter, but due to the selector name.

```
func buttonPressed(buttonNum: Int, packet: Packet?)
```

should get a

```
buttonPressed:packet:
```

Objective-C function. Yours is `buttonPressed::` - no label for the second parameter.

The confusion might have been caused by the fact that Swift automatically infers labels starting with the second parameter - if no label is specified, then the label is assumed to be the parameter name. This is why in Swift you'd need to call the protocol function as `buttonPressed(arg1, packet: arg2)`.

Now you can either add the `packet` label to the Objective-C selector, or you can remove it from the Swift function declaration, like this:

```
func buttonPressed(buttonNum: Int, _ packet: Packet?)
```

You can then call it from Swift like `buttonPressed(arg1, arg2)`. It's up to you which approach you choose, although I'd recommend going with the labeled one as is more clear, at least in Objective-C.